# how do I change the href link dynamically?

Tags: javascript, facebook

how do I change the `href` link dynamically ?

```
<link rel="image_src" href="" id="ShareImageID"/>
```

so that when someone share the web page on facebook the thumbnail shows specific image from that link tag.

I do not want to change the link for each page.

I also tried to use the og:image, it worked but I was not able to change it dynamically. I also tried this

```
<script>
var ShareImageIdVar = location.href.match(/\d+/);
document.getElementById('ShareImageID').href = 
        "http://www.mysite.com/Images/"+ ShareImageIdVar +".jpg";
</script>
```

but it is not working :( facebook is still choosing another thumbnail. a random one.

Comment: sorry i have no idea what you are actually trying to ask, be more specific?

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: well the problem is facebook is still choosing another thumbnail.

Comment: Is your question more like how do I get Facebook to select a certain thumbnail image when sharing the page?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the Facebook image with JavaScript. When you share a link on Facebook, Facebook scrapes the page looking for images. This scrape doesn't run JavaScript.

You will need to change the image server side, possibly with PHP.

Comment: how do I do that? any tutorial video or article please ?

Comment: That's another question entirely. What server side language are you using? Where are you getting the file path from? Accept an answer to your first question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Facebook to select the proper image when your link is posted, you need to have the proper OpenGraph image chosen in the `<head>` of your php file.

you can read more about open graph here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Make sure to have all the necessary OG elements, for it to work properly.

Since you are asking about the image, you should have something like this:

```
 <head>
 <meta property="og:image" content="/images/pageimage.png" />
 </head>
```

To dynamically alter it, just use an `echo` that is specific to the php page
edit/like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo "$imageurl" ?> />
```

just set the variable `$imageurl` specifically on each php page.

Comment: As facebook suggested I can put it this way '<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
but I do not want to add a link to each page
'

Comment: yeah thats fine, a full url, what about it?

Comment: i want to change the content link through a function ?

Comment: I want the link to be something like this : var ShareImageIdVar = location.href.match(/\d+/);
document.getElementById('ShareImageID').href = 
        "http://www.mysite.com/Images/"+ ShareImageIdVar +".jpg";

Comment: do you need it to be in javascript? i dont think thats possible